# Javascript not functioning with IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a dropdown whose list is dependent on what is selected in another dropdown. The dropdown is populated by javascript. It works correctly in Chrome and FF but not in IE, all I get is a blank dropdown.

Here is the relevant code: price and mileage are 2 js arrays that hold the required info

```
var serviceMileage='<select name=\'servicing\' id=\'servicing\''+ 
'onfocus=\'setStyle(this.id);\''+
'onblur=\'setStyleBack(this.id);\'>';

for (var i=0;i<mileage.length;i++)
{serviceMileage=serviceMileage+'<option value='+price[i]+'>'+mileage[i]+'</option>'}
serviceMileage=serviceMileage+'</select>';

document.getElementById('servicing').innerHTML=serviceMileage;
```

Any pointers gratefully received!

Comment: is this in a dom ready state?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: And he go away, without any information... What a people.

Answer (score 0):

Try write in this way:

```
var serviceMileage="<select name='servicing' id='servicing' onfocus='setStyle(this.id); onblur='setStyleBack(this.id);'>";

for (var i=0;i<mileage.length;i++){
    serviceMileage=serviceMileage+"<option value='"+price[i]+"'>"+mileage[i]+"</option>"
}
serviceMileage=serviceMileage+'</select>';

document.getElementById('servicing').innerHTML=serviceMileage;
```

Your problem is here probably:

```
... value='+price[i]+' ...
```

it should be

**`... value='"+price[i]+"'...`**